# Scoring profile with weights and a function

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure Search with a scoring profile.  I need text fields along with quantity sold to be a part of the scoring profile.  I can configure the following profile, but the quantity sold doesn't seem to be factored in to the search score when I query the index.  I'm thinking because quantity sold isn't a string, its an int.  Therefore, I can't make the field searchable?  I'm using the new featuresMode parameter in the query, the quantity sold field doesn't even appear in the scoring breakdown

```
 "scoringProfiles": [
{
  "name": "Product Name",
  "functions": [
    {
      "fieldName": "QuantitySold",
      "freshness": null,
      "interpolation": "linear",
      "magnitude": {
        "boostingRangeStart": 0,
        "boostingRangeEnd": 100000,
        "constantBoostBeyondRange": true
      },
      "distance": null,
      "tag": null,
      "type": "magnitude",
      "boost": 6
    }
  ],
  "functionAggregation": "sum",
  "text": {
    "weights": {
      "ProductName": 4,
      "ProductSet": 3,
      "ProductDesc": 2
    }
  }
}
```

],

Answer (score 0):

What type of boost you should use depends on the datatype. An int like QuantitySold should use type magnitude for boosting. A date would use type freshness and so on.

I recreated a minimal example with the simplest possible index with only two properties: Id and Title.

CREATE INDEX

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://{{SEARCH_SVC}}.{{DNS_SUFFIX}}/$metadata#indexes/$entity",
"@odata.etag": "\"0x8D8761DCBBCCD00\"",
"name": "{{INDEX}}",
"defaultScoringProfile": null,
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "Id",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "facetable": false,
        "filterable": true,
        "key": true,
        "retrievable": true,
        "searchable": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "analyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "synonymMaps": [],
        "fields": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Title",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "facetable": false,
        "filterable": true,
        "key": false,
        "retrievable": true,
        "searchable": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "analyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "synonymMaps": [],
        "fields": []
    },
    {
        "name": "QuantitySold",
        "type": "Edm.Int32",
        "facetable": true,
        "filterable": true,
        "key": false,
        "retrievable": true,
        "searchable": false,
        "sortable": true,
        "analyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "synonymMaps": [],
        "fields": []
    }
],  "scoringProfiles": [  
{  
  "name": "relevance",  
  "text": {  
    "weights": {  
      "Title": 1.5
    }  
  }  
},  
{  
  "name": "sales",  
  "functions": [  
    {
      "type": "magnitude",  
      "fieldName": "QuantitySold",  
      "boost": 100,  
      "interpolation": "linear",  
      "magnitude": {  
        "boostingRangeStart": 1,  
        "boostingRangeEnd": 100000,  
        "constantBoostBeyondRange": false  
      }  
    }  
  ]  
} ],"corsOptions": null,    "suggesters": [],    "analyzers": [],    "tokenizers": ],    "tokenFilters": [],    "charFilters": [],    "encryptionKey": null}
```

UPLOAD MINIMAL

I then submit two products. One called *Apple iPhone* with a low sales quantity. And *Apple Juice* with a high sales quantity.

```
{
"value": [
    {
        "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
        "Id": "2",
        "Title": "Apple Juice",
        "QuantitySold": 10000
    },
    {
        "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
        "Id": "1",
        "Title": "Apple iPhone",
        "QuantitySold": 35
    }           
]
```

}

QUERY

Without using any scoring profile, I query for *apple*. As expected, the two items are equally relevant responses to my query. They both match one of two tokens. Both get score 0.25811607

```
https://{{SEARCH_SVC}}.{{DNS_SUFFIX}}/indexes/{{INDEX}}/docs?search=apple&$count=true&searchMode=all&queryType=full&api-version={{API-VERSION}}&featuresMode=enabled

{
"@odata.count": 2,
"value": [
    {
        "@search.score": 0.25811607,
        "@search.features": {
            "Title": {
                "uniqueTokenMatches": 1.0,
                "similarityScore": 0.25811607,
                "termFrequency": 1.0
            }
        },
        "Id": "2",
        "Title": "Apple Juice",
        "QuantitySold": 10000
    },
    {
        "@search.score": 0.25811607,
        "@search.features": {
            "Title": {
                "uniqueTokenMatches": 1.0,
                "similarityScore": 0.25811607,
                "termFrequency": 1.0
            }
        },
        "Id": "1",
        "Title": "Apple iPhone",
        "QuantitySold": 35
    }
]
```

}

QUERY WITH BOOST ON QUANTITY SOLD

I then repeat the query for *apple*, but this time I boost items with a high QuantitySold by selecting my scoring profile called *sales*. This boosts our Apple Juice item to the top with a score of 2.8123235. The Apple iPhone item has also received a boost, but much smaller with only a score of  0.26680434.

https://{{SEARCH_SVC}}.{{DNS_SUFFIX}}/indexes/{{INDEX}}/docs?search=apple&$count=true&searchMode=all&queryType=full&api-version={{API-VERSION}}&featuresMode=enabled&scoringProfile=sales

```
{
"@odata.count": 2,
"value": [
    {
        "@search.score": 2.813235,
        "@search.features": {
            "Title": {
                "uniqueTokenMatches": 1.0,
                "similarityScore": 0.25811607,
                "termFrequency": 1.0
            }
        },
        "Id": "2",
        "Title": "Apple Juice",
        "QuantitySold": 10000
    },
    {
        "@search.score": 0.26680434,
        "@search.features": {
            "Title": {
                "uniqueTokenMatches": 1.0,
                "similarityScore": 0.25811607,
                "termFrequency": 1.0
            }
        },
        "Id": "1",
        "Title": "Apple iPhone",
        "QuantitySold": 35
    }
]
```

}